# Проблема с transform и z-index на всех устройствах IOS

Tags: css3, ios, safari, transform, z-index

Есть блок, который крутится посредством JS и изменения свойства **transform: rotate**, перед этим блоком есть еще один блок, который совершает 3d поворот при наведении(в перспективе), посредством rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -15deg), пример тут (https://codepen.io/Cubic_bear/pen/oNxPwvE)

```
 <div class="wr">
  <div id="front-element">
    
  </div>
    <div id="back-circle">
      <div id="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>


    .wr{
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
      perspective: 300px;
}
#back-circle{
      width: 400px;
    height: 400px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 1000px;
      -moz-transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
    -o-transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
    transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.55, 1);
}
#line{
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
#front-element{
  width: 280px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
      -moz-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1);
    -o-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1);
    -moz-transform-style: flat;
    -o-transform-style: flat;
    -webkit-transform-style: flat;
    transform-style: flat;
}
#front-element:hover {
      -moz-transform: translateX(60px) translateZ(2px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -15deg) scale(.9);
    -o-transform: translateX(60px) translateZ(2px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -15deg) scale(.9);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(60px) translateZ(2px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -15deg) scale(.9);
    transform: translateX(60px) translateZ(2px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -15deg) scale(.9);
}
```

Собственно проблема в том, что при наведении на зеленый блок, который стоит перед вращающимся блоком, в нормальных браузерах происходит все нормально, а вот в семействе IOS поворачивающийся блок, какбы разрывает(пересекает) вращающийся. При этом все префиксы -webkit- и прочие в наличии, также стоит     **-webkit-transform-style: flat;** Но на ios все ужасно.

как это исправить?